# Prove that QFT and Walsh-Hadamard gates give the same output when acting on $\lvert x\rangle\lvert 0\rangle$

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics, quantum-fourier-transform, hadamard

I know that $QFT_n|0\rangle$ is equivalent to $H_n|0\rangle$
([mathematical proof](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9769/why-qft-can-be-replaced-by-hadamard-gates)).

And it is also easy to prove that $QFT_1$ is equivalent to $H_1$ (applied to one QuBit).

From looking at the circuit below it seems clear to me that the gates should also be equivalent if $|x_1\rangle$ is in any state and all other QuBits are $|0\rangle$.
This should be true because none of the controlled $R$ gates are applied to $|x_1\rangle$.

I do not know how to prove this mathematically. Can anyone provide an elegant proof?

[image: from wikipedia 3]

Comment: No my question is slightly different. I ask for a prove that x_1 qubit can be in any state, and qft is still equivalent to walsh.

Comment: *"This should be true because none of the controlled R gates are applied"* ***is*** a mathematical proof (if you replace "should be" by "is").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your explanation based on the circuit is perfectly adequate.

For a more rigorous "proof", why not simply take the output of the circuit? Substitute in $x_i=0$ for all $i$ and see that all the outputs are $(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ for $i\neq 1$ and $(|0\rangle+(-1)^{x_1}|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ for $i=1$, exactly as it would be for the Hadamard transform.

Alternatively, simply repeat the proof in the [answer you cite](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9771/1837) for two inputs: $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ and $|1\rangle|0\rangle^{\otimes(n-1)}$. If it works for those two, by linearity it must work for any input on the first qubit.